# Wildfly ContextService concurrent securityIdentity is null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, queue, wildfly

I am trying to send an object over a queue. The object is wrapped in the createContextualProxy of the ContextService. But if I am unwrap the object, the securityIdentity is null. The object is a correct Proxy.

Sender:

```
@Resource(name = "DefaultContextService")
private ContextService cs;

public void sendMessage() {
    ObjectMessage objectMessage = context.createObjectMessage();
    objectMessage.setObject((Serializable) cs.createContextualProxy(<ObjectToSend>, 
            Runnable.class));            
    context.createProducer().send(queue, objectMessage);
}
```

Receiver:

```
ObjectMessage message = (ObjectMessage) msg;                
Runnable myObject = (Runnable) message.getObject();
myObject.run();
```

The runnable myObject is a Proxy. But the securityIdentity=null.

Did anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to incorporate the security identity of the user directly into the object that you are sending.

**Security context information is not retained in the contextual proxy because WildFly (up to 15.0.1) is broken.**

JMS requires ObjectMessage payloads to be Serializable. However the security identity object retained in the proxy (a [org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity](https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/auth/server/SecurityIdentity.java) object) is not Serializable, so it is declared `transient` in the [org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.IdentityAwareProxyInvocationHandler](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/ee/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/ee/concurrent/IdentityAwareProxyInvocationHandler.java) proxy implementation.

Consequently it does not survive the subsequent JMS message serialisation/deserialization process.

There is an old [WildFly issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4308) that has been closed, but I know that the security implementation has been completely replaced since then...

Comment: But I thought this ContextualProxy is exactly for this. After create the ContextualProxy the securityIdentity is correctly set, but after reading it from the queue, its null. **Thanks a lot**